# Lotus Notes Two forms same document

Tags: lotus-notes

Going back to the basics. I want to have two forms to view a document. But if document was created using Form A then always display Form A, if document was created using Form B then always display Form B when opening that document (but they must have the same alias and form name as far as the views are concerned). I don't want to change any of my current application logic, neither do I want to change my view formulas in order to have this Form B (form A already exists). Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this.  It sounds to me like it's going to make your life really difficult in the long run.  But, I guess you must have a reason, so here's what I would do:

- Copy Form A into Subform A.  At the bottom, add a Computed-When-Composed field OriginalForm, and set the value formula to "A".
- Copy Form B into Subform B.  At the bottom, add a Computed-When-Composed field OriginalForm, and set the value formula to "B".
- Delete the original forms.
- Make a new Form A with a Computed Subform, and set the formula to "Subform " + OriginalForm.
- Make a new Form B with a Computed Subform, and set the formula to "Subform " + OriginalForm.

Comment: Many thanks - I am still thinking of other ways to get around this problem using hide-whens, but it's good to know whether it's possible. Thanks for the subform idea - this gives me an idea, I could also move my current form into a subform and then use computed subforms to control what gets displayed in a single form.

Comment: Richard - could I not change my buttons that open or edit this document - using wks.EditDocument and then specifying form at the end? Haven't tried this yet, but was thinking about this option.

Comment: The EditDocument does not allow you to specify a form.  It will use either the value of the Form item in the document, or the result of the Form Formula of the current view.

Comment: Thanks - I have just realised it's compose document, rather than edit document! We could really use a DisplayForm field as well as Form field in Notes!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Form Formula in your view. If could contain a simple formula like

```
@If(FormWasUsed="FormA"; "FormA"; "FormB")
```

or just plain

```
FormWasUsed
```

Comment: I thought about suggesting this, but he specified he didn't want to change any existing application logic or view formulas.  I'm guessing that's because there are a lot of views.

Comment: Could very well be, but it is the only other reasonable alternative to your subform solution. Moreover, when the subform solution is implemented he'll probably need this when he wants to open the document with the original form (I assume).

Comment: Thanks D.Bugger, although this isn't going to work because I don't want to change the logic and view formulas as Richard rightly pointed out.

Comment: IMHO a view formula is not the same as a form formula... Apparently, you don't want to change the view, at all, period. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using computed subforms and hide-whens on fields and labels.

As Richard suggests, create two subforms that contain the labels and fields that are unique to "Form A" and "Form B". Make sure to have a "document type" field on the main form that indicates which subform will be used for that document. All common information goes on the main form, so that all documents appear in all the views and use the existing application logic.

If the different labels and fields are either non-contiguous or few in number, just add those fields with hide-when formulas based on the "document type" field.

You can't have two forms that have the same name and alias. You can have two forms with the same alias, but this is best used for forms that are available only to the Notes client or only to the Web client. Otherwise, the client won't know which form to use, since both are available -- I would suspect it would only use one, but that is not what you want.